# I get a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsExeption: Invalid index 9, size is 5

Tags: java, android

I keep getting this exeption when I am removing and placing a item from one array-list to another.
Sometimes the index is 13 and size is 5. other times is 0 and 0. It happens at random and more often on slower devices.

```
11-05 19:42:34.487: W/dalvikvm(2232): threadid=14: thread exiting with uncaught exception   (group=0x40c3ca68)
11-05 19:42:34.497: E/AndroidRuntime(2232): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-491
11-05 19:42:34.497: E/AndroidRuntime(2232): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index size is 5
11-05 19:42:34.497: E/AndroidRuntime(2232):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
11-05 19:42:34.497: E/AndroidRuntime(2232):     at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:143)
11-05 19:42:34.497: E/AndroidRuntime(2232):     at com.pigeoncraft.pigeoncraft.entity.Inventory.add(Inventory.java:25)
11-05 19:42:34.497: E/AndroidRuntime(2232):     at com.pigeoncraft.pigeoncraft.screen.ContainerMenu.tick(ContainerMenu.java:62)
11-05 19:42:34.497: E/AndroidRuntime(2232):     at com.pigeoncraft.pigeoncraft.Game.tick(Game.java:312)
11-05 19:42:34.497: E/AndroidRuntime(2232):     at com.pigeoncraft.pigeoncraft.Game.iterate(Game.java:265)
11-05 19:42:34.497: E/AndroidRuntime(2232):     at com.pigeoncraft.pigeoncraft.GameActivity$2.run(GameActivity.java:128)
11-05 19:42:34.497: E/AndroidRuntime(2232):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Here is the code for Inventory.

```
    package com.mojang.ld22.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import  com.pigeoncraft.pigeoncraft.item.Item;
import  com.pigeoncraft.pigeoncraft.ResourceItem;
import  com.pigeoncraft.pigeoncraft.Resource;

public class Inventory  implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8246630353617240883L;

public List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();

public void add(Item item) {
    add(items.size(), item);
}

public void add(int slot, Item item) {
    if (item instanceof ResourceItem) {
        ResourceItem toTake = (ResourceItem) item;
        ResourceItem has = findResource(toTake.resource);
        if (has == null) {
            items.add(slot, toTake); <--------------------
        } else {
            has.count += toTake.count;
        }
    } else {
        items.add(slot, item);
    }
}

private ResourceItem findResource(Resource resource) {
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        if (items.get(i) instanceof ResourceItem) {
            ResourceItem has = (ResourceItem) items.get(i);
            if (has.resource.name.equals(resource.name))
            {
                return has;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public boolean hasResources(Resource r, int count) {
    ResourceItem ri = findResource(r);
    if (ri == null) return false;
    return ri.count >= count;
}

public boolean removeResource(Resource r, int count) {
    ResourceItem ri = findResource(r);
    if (ri == null) return false;
    if (ri.count < count) return false;
    ri.count -= count;
    if (ri.count <= 0) items.remove(ri);
    return true;
}

public int count(Item item) {
    if (item instanceof ResourceItem) {
        ResourceItem ri = findResource(((ResourceItem)item).resource);
        if (ri!=null) return ri.count;
    } else {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i=0; i<items.size(); i++) {
            if (items.get(i).matches(item)) count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
    return 0;
}
}
```

Comment: Exactly what the error says; from your `tick()` method, you're calling `add(9, ...)`, and there are only 5 elements in the array.

Comment: I could not understand why you are using `add(index, element)` instead of `add(element)`. Can you explain?

Comment: Seems like you always add to the end of the ArrayList. add(E) will suffice for that, as that's the way it works.

Comment: If you have a really good reason for adding items at specific locations, not just at the end, you need to reach a high index by adding e.g. null until the ArrayList is big enough.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan At that point I would recommend a `Map<Integer, Item>`.

Comment: I think @BheshGurung may have fixed it. It hasn't thrown a error yet. Ill send a beta out tonight and see if I can get others to throw the error.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what your code is doing when it adds / removes objects from the ArrayList, it's still pretty obvious that this code is not at all threadsafe because none of your methods / variables are synchronized.  The ArrayList itself is, because Java gives that to you for free, but your add method never even checks to see if you are trying to insert an object at an supportable index.  Before you call add, you should at the very least check to see if `slot >= items.length()` so you can just append it to the end of the list or exit more gracefully at the very least

Comment: Can you please clarify "because Java gives that to you for free"? `ArrayList` isn't threadsafe.